# Using named parameters as controller input versus FormCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC so this could have an obvious answer.  Right now I have a form in my view with a lot of input controls, so I have an action that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string formItemOne, int? formItemTwo, etc...)
```

It has like a dozen parameters, which is pretty ugly.  I'm trying to change it to this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection formItems)
```

and then parse the items dynamically.  But when I change to a FormCollection, the form items no longer "automagically" remember their values through postbacks.  Why would changing to a FormCollection change this behavior?  Anything simple I can do to get it working automagically again?

Thanks for the help,

~ Justin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to use models instead of manipulating the raw values. Like this:

```
class MyModel
{
  public string ItemOne { get; set; }
  public int? ItemTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this code:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
  // Do things with model.

  return this.View(model);
}
```

In your view:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyModel>" %>
<%= Html.TextBox("ItemOne", Model.ItemOne) %>
<%= Html.TextBox("ItemTwo", Model.ItemTwo) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace your big list of parameters with a single one, use a [view model](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx). If after the POST you return this model to your view, then your view will remember the values posted.

A view model is simply an class with your action parameters as public properties. For example, you could do something like this, replacing:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string formItemOne, int? formItemTwo, etc...)
```

with

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormItems formItems)
{
  //your code...
  return View(formItems);
}
```

where FormItems is

```
public class FormItems
{
  public property string formItemOne {get; set;}
  public property int? formItemTwo {get; set;}
}
```

You may see a complete example in Stephen Walter's post  [ASP.NET MVC Tip #50 – Create View Models](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because they aren't magically inserted into the ModelState dictionary anymore. Try inserting them there.

If you use UpdateModel() or TryUpdateModel() I think the values are gonna be persisted.